# Why does this date parsing fail?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to convert a string into a LocalDateTime object.

```
@Test
public void testDateFormat() {
   String date = "20171205014657111";
   DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
       DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
   LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
}
```

I would expect this test to pass.

I get the following error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20171205014657111' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: Works fine on my machine: `dt = 2017-12-05T01:46:57.111`

Comment: @alfasin which jvm version are you running?

Comment: Works fine here. What timezone are you in?

Comment: Timezone shouldn't make a difference - it's LocalDateTime.

Comment: @user4184113 Java 9+181

Answer (score 17):

Looks like I may have run across this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085 as it corresponds to the JVM version I'm using. The workaround in the comments fixes the issue for me:

```
@Test
public void testDateFormat() {
    String date = "20171205014657111";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
       .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
       .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3).toFormatter();
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, dtf);
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow, that's disappointing.  I wonder why they're deferring it to 9, instead of fixing it in the next build of 8.